# iOS crash NSISEngine dealloc

Tags: ios, crash-reports

this is my crash log ,What is the cause of the crash？I really need your help！Give me some advice,please.
Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001af2a2160 objc_release + 16 (objc-runtime-new.h:1585)
1   Foundation                      0x000000019c49ea7c empty + 76 (NSMapTable.m:60)
2   Foundation                      0x000000019c3c8edc -[NSConcreteMapTable removeAllItems] + 80 (NSMapTable.m:1151)
3   CoreAutoLayout                  0x00000001af509d84 -[NSISEngine dealloc] + 132 (NSISEngine.m:1480)
4   UIKitCore                       0x000000019dfbaa54 -[UIView _layoutConstraintCleanup] + 508 (UIView.m:4580)
5   UIKitCore                       0x000000019dfbab20 -[UIView dealloc] + 144 (UIView.m:4593)
6   UIKitCore                       0x000000019d12ab08 -[UIToolbar dealloc] + 60 (UIToolbar.m:750)
7   UIKitCore                       0x000000019d595960 -[UIWebFormAccessory .cxx_destruct] + 232 (UIWebFormAccessory.m:53)
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001af283324 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 112 (objc-class.mm:455)
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001af299d38 objc_destructInstance + 80 (objc-class.mm:469)
10  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001af2a099c _objc_rootDealloc + 68 (objc-runtime-new.mm:8131)
11  UIKitCore                       0x000000019daeea6c -[UIResponder dealloc] + 156 (UIResponder.m:136)
12  UIKitCore                       0x000000019dfbae18 -[UIView dealloc] + 904 (UIView.m:4636)
13  UIKitCore                       0x000000019d73f880 -[UIInputView dealloc] + 168 (UIInputView.m:305)
14  UIKitCore                       0x000000019d594574 -[UIWebFormAccessory dealloc] + 108 (UIWebFormAccessory.m:175)
15  WebKit                          0x00000001a71c843c -[WKContentView .cxx_destruct] + 1740 (RetainPtr.h:174)
16  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001af283324 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 112 (objc-class.mm:455)
17  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001af299d38 objc_destructInstance + 80 (objc-class.mm:469)
18  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001af2a099c _objc_rootDealloc + 68 (objc-runtime-new.mm:8131)
19  UIKitCore                       0x000000019daeea6c -[UIResponder dealloc] + 156 (UIResponder.m:136)
20  UIKitCore                       0x000000019dfbae18 -[UIView dealloc] + 904 (UIView.m:4636)
21  WebKit                          0x00000001a71c5580 -[WKContentView dealloc] + 132 (WKContentView.mm:299)
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019ad94ac8 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:559)
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019ada204c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 836 (inline_internal.h:2548)
24  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019b1131e4 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 16 (CFRunLoop.c:1790)
25  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019b10d3b4 __CFRunLoopRun + 2508 (CFRunLoop.c:3118)
26  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019b10c4bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
27  GraphicsServices                0x00000001b1c1e820 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2259)
28  UIKitCore                       0x000000019dab9164 -[UIApplication _run] + 1072 (UIApplication.m:3270)
29  UIKitCore                       0x000000019dabe840 UIApplicationMain + 168 (UIApplication.m:4739)
30  SHRB_UAT                        0x000000010493e5e4 main + 72 (main.m:47)
31  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019add3e40 start + 4 (:-1)

```
I get this crash log from testflight users,and I don't know how to reproduce it while debugging.
```

Comment: Reformat the crash text so it’s readable. Then post it on the internal Apple forums.